# What does ECONNABORTED mean when trying to connect a socket?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using python 2.7 on an ubuntu machine.

The client tries to connect to the server.  I get a EINPROGRESS which is expected for non-blocking sockets.

To check whether or not the connection succeeded, I do what the man page for {connect} suggest:

```
# EINPROGRESS The socket is nonblocking and the connection cannot be
# completed immediately.  It is possible to select(2) or poll(2) for
# completion by selecting the socket for writing.  After select(2)
# indicates writability, use getsockopt(2) to read the SO_ERROR option at
# level SOL_SOCKET to determine whether connect() completed successfully
# (SO_ERROR is zero) or unsuccessfully (SO_ERROR is one of the usual error
# codes listed here, explaining the reason for the failure)
```

When the server is offline, this gives me a ECONNREFUSED.  So far so good.

When the connection fails, I want to try again a few times.

**Problem**: the second time I try to connect that same socket, {connect} sends me ECONNABORTED.  This one isn't in the man page of {connect}.  What does it mean?

Comment: Even if you get this to work, if I were you, I wouldn't do it. I don't know whether the sockets API technically allows reusing a socket that failed to connect once before, but while Linux doesn't seem to mind, I get EINVAL on MacOS. Open a new socket every time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ECONNABORTED` is set in two places of the Linux Kernel Source Socket Code.

As per the `errno` man page and **/include/asm-generic/errno.h**

`#define ECONNABORTED    103     /* Software caused connection abort */`

The [first](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/socket.c#L1533) is in the function that defines the syscall `accept4` in **/net/socket.c**.

**Relevant Source Code**

```
1533         if (upeer_sockaddr) {
1534                 if (newsock->ops->getname(newsock, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
1535                                           &len, 2) < 0) {
1536                         err = -ECONNABORTED;
1537                         goto out_fd;
1538                 }
1539                 err = move_addr_to_user((struct sockaddr *)&address,
1540                                         len, upeer_sockaddr, upeer_addrlen);
1541                 if (err < 0)
1542                         goto out_fd;
1543         }
```

The relevant explanation of logic is below.

If the address of the peer socket from userspace is defined
and If the  new socket doesn't have name, then set error state to `ECONNABORTED` and goto the label `out_fd`.

The [second](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/af_inet.c#L663) is in the function that defines the symbol `inet_stream_connect` in **/net/ipv4/af_inet.c**.

**Relevant Source Code**

```
645         /* Connection was closed by RST, timeout, ICMP error
646          * or another process disconnected us.
647          */
648         if (sk->sk_state == TCP_CLOSE)
649                 goto sock_error; 

662 sock_error:
663         err = sock_error(sk) ? : -ECONNABORTED;
664         sock->state = SS_UNCONNECTED;
665         if (sk->sk_prot->disconnect(sk, flags))
666                 sock->state = SS_DISCONNECTING;
667         goto out;
```

The relevant explanation of logic is below.

The only code that has a goto to the `sock_error` label in `inet_stream_connect` is the check to see if the socket was closed by RST,timeout, another process or error.

In the `sock_error` label
If we can recover a socket error report, do so , otherwise the error state to `ECONNABORTED`

Like **Celada**'s comment I also recommend opening a new socket each time.

Comment: Sweet.  I had no idea the linux kernel had to many gotos :).  I used to find the "software caused connection abort" totally under-informative, but in the light of the code you cited it makes more sense.  I think that the second one applies to my case.  I'll create new sockets then, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

See the manual page for errno. On FreeBSD you can find it as `intro`(2). It says:

> 53 ECONNABORTED Software caused connection abort.  A connection abort was caused internal to your host machine.

As to why this happens, you'd have to look in the Linux kernel source for sockets. On FreeBSD only `accept` seems return ECONNABORTED.